# Show a marker with URL schema on google maps iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, url-scheme

With iOS 6 google maps, I can open the map by:
comgooglemaps://?center=37.759748,-122.427135

But I cannot show a marker to show the centre, how can I show one with this URL schema? Thanks.